# Using Parallel::ForkManager in foreach loop

Tags: arrays, multithreading, perl

I am just learning Perl as a fourth language.

My wish is to use [`Parallel::ForkManager`](https://metacpan.org/module/Parallel%3a%3aForkManager) to speed up a `foreach` loop using an array whose members are taken from a text file.

Basically I am testing a .txt file of URLs, and wish to make it so that it will test multiple members of the array at once, not one at a time (five at a time in this instance) and without spamming the same URL inadvertently DoSing it.

Would something like this do the trick?

```
$limit = new Parallel::ForkManager(5);

foreach (@lines) {

  $limit->start and next;
  $lines = $_;

  ... do processing here ...

  $limit->finish;
}
```

or would it be the equivalent of running that loop 5 times making a small multithreaded DoS script?

Comment: Won't $lines=$_ mess up your loop? Try "print $lines\n" and see what gets printed out.

Comment: not sure what you mean by "equivalent of running that loop 5 times"; it will run up to 5 child processes at a time, yes.

Comment: I've actually used this method before, but without the forking. Simply because i wish to perform screening on the contents of $lines(removing chars etc) and it seems to work fine, it gets overwritten each iteration. I was unsure  if this was gonna fall over upon conversion to multithreading is more what i'm getting at here.

Comment: But will each one be donig the same thing, IE the loop takes 5 times as long, or will it run them in such a way that the loop will be 5 times faster (what i am aiming for)

Comment: depending what you are doing, it will be 5 times faster.  but you keep saying multithreading; this isn't multithreading (unless you are on windows, where fork is emulated by threads?)

Comment: Roughly speaking, that will make your program run 5 times faster than without P::FM, thus multiplying the load on the servers by 5. // A polite spider is one that spends as much time between requests to a server as it does waiting for a response from that server. You should be slowing it down, not speeding it up.

Comment: I agree that the comments I've deleted were pointless. Hopefully only on-topic, helpful comments will come now. Thanks! (Just for the record; the OP above was not involved in the deleted discussions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't too clear from the documentation, but

- A call to `start` will *block* in the parent process until there are fewer children running than the limit specified. Then it will return the (non-zero) child PID in the parent, and zero in the child
- A child process can see all the data in the parent process as it was when the `start` was called. The data is presumably copy-on-write, as the child may modify it but the changes aren't reflected in any other process's workspace
- The `$pm->start and next` idiom may seem a little obscure. Essentially it skips the rest of the loop if the `start` method returns a *true* value. I prefer something like `my $pid = $fm->start; next if $pid;` or the `if` construct in the code below. Both do the same thing, but I think more legibly

I recommend that you experiment with this simpler application, which uses a cache of five child threads to print the numbers from zero to nine.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Parallel::ForkManager;

STDOUT->autoflush;

my $fm = Parallel::ForkManager->new(5);

for my $i (0 .. 9) {
  my $pid = $fm->start;
  if ($pid == 0) {
    print "$i\n";
    sleep 2;
    $fm->finish;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To test, use a safe local process like print or write to avoid spamming the URL's. Here's a working snippet from a program I wrote that uses the fork manager.

```
my $pm=new Parallel::ForkManager(20);

foreach $add (@adds){ 

    $pm->start and next;

        #if email is invalid move on
        if (!defined(Email::Valid::Loose->address($add))){
            writeaddr(*BADADDR, $add); #address is bad
            $pm->finish;
        }

        #if email is valid get domain name 
        $is_valid = Email::Valid::Loose->address($add);
        if ($is_valid =~ m/\@(.*)$/) {
            $host = $1;
        }
        $is_valid="";

        # perform dsn lookup to check domain
        @mx=mx($resolver, $host);

        if (@mx) {
            writeaddr(*GOODADDR, $add); #address is good
            }else{
            writeaddr(*BADADDR, $add); #address is bad
        }

    $pm->finish;
}
```

Comment: Okay, i found this loop acts as desired, thanks. How shall i best answer my own question so that it will help anyone else who has the same issue?

Comment: Am I missing something? This looks the same as the OP's code except for some irrelevant statements between the `start` and the `finish`